# Bixby Capsule asks for login indefinitely

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am working on enabling Bixby Oauth2 Authorization on some actions.
I have configured the `authorization.bxb` as follows:

```
authorization {
  user {
    oauth2-authorization-code (PROVIDER) {
      authorize-endpoint (https://X.com/authorize)
      client-id (userId)
      client-secret-key (password)
      login-button-label(LOGIN)
      token-endpoint (https://X.com/token)
    }
  }
}
```

I have declared my endpoint like:

```
action-endpoint (MyAuthenticatedAction) {
  accepted-inputs ($vivContext)
  local-endpoint (myAuthenticatedAction.js)
  authorization {
    user
  }
}
```

Bixby successfully shows up popup to login and opens up X.com for authorization. After authorization a callback is done to Bixby with `code` and `state` parameters.
Bixby now sends the `code` received from the callback to token-endpoint. But even after getting a success response from the route (as per server logs), Bixby again shows the login popup.

The response of token-endpoint is:

```
{
  "access_token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Bixby continues to show the Login popup yet after receiving the response. Bixby debugger does not help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question might require some more information about your capsule.

I'd recommend experiencing the behavior again and reaching out to the support team via the "Contact Support" option in Bixby Studio's Help dropdown menu.

This will give the Support team additional diagnostics to investigate further.